# NodeHandle::getParam() is unable to resolve Environmental variables

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosparam, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launchfile in which I want to specify the path to a specific file, e.g. `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`. Normally, I would just use the `<param>` tag like this:

```
<param name="haarcascade_filename" type="string" value="$(env ROS_ROOT)/../OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" />
```

and try to load it during initialization using `NodeHandle::param()`:

```
ros::NodeHandle local_nh("~");
local_nh.param("haarcascade_filename", name_, std::string(""));
```

This is the way it is done for example in the `face_detector` stack. Assume that I now want to specify multiple files using a `<rosparam>` list:

```
<rosparam param="haarcascade_filename_list">["$(env ROS_ROOT)/../OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml", "morestrings.."]</rosparam>
```

This is the way I'm trying to load all the entries of the list:

```
    XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue my_xmlrpc_haarlist;
    local_nh.getParam("haarcascade_filename_list", my_xmlrpc_haarlist);
    ROS_ASSERT(my_xmlrpc_haarlist.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < my_xmlrpc_haarlist.size(); ++i) {
        ROS_ASSERT(my_xmlrpc_haarlist[i].getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeString);
        haar_filename_list_.push_back(static_cast<std::string> (my_xmlrpc_haarlist[i]));
    }
```

The problem is if I now do `ROS_INFO_STREAM("Filename: " << supername_);` and `ROS_INFO_STREAM("Filename list: " << haar_filename_list_.at(0));` the results are not the same:

```
[ INFO] [1354712164.859028413]: Filename: /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/../OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
[ INFO] [1354712164.859087292]: Filename list: $(env ROS_ROOT)/../OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
```

How do I solve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49764/nodehandle::getparam()-is-unable-to-resolve-environmental-variables/) by [Random-I-Am](https://answers.ros.org/users/2088/random-i-am/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a limitation of roslaunch. You cannot use `$(env ...)`, `$(find ...)` and similar expressions when setting parameters in a launch file using yaml syntax. Instead of expanding paths in roslaunch, I would instead specify them as package relative URIs, e.g. `package://foo/bar` to reference the file `bar` in ROS package `foo`. To resolve these URIs, you can use the [resource_retriever](http://ros.org/wiki/resource_retriever) package.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-05**:
If you just want to retrieve the resouce name, but not load the actual file, you can use ros::package::getPath - http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/roslib/html/c++/namespaceros_1_1package.html#ae9470dd201aa4e66abb833e710d812a4